# Geometry question about a triangle in a circle

Tags: geometry

Circumscribe triangle $ABC$. Extend $B$ to a point $P$ on the circumference of the circle. Now extend the line $AB$ to a point $P_1$. Why is $\angle BAC + \angle BPP_1 + \angle BPP_3= 180^\circ$?

[image]

Comment: Isn't B already on the circle?

Comment: Yes, B is on the circle. I said circumscribe triangle ABC. The points A, B and C touch the circumference of the circle.

Comment: Can you put some image with all elements and points on it? Mabe it's just me, but it's not really clear what exactly you're doing.

Comment: The point P creates a cyclic quadrilateral ABPC. Hold on I will try to post a pic.

Comment: So wait, $P_1$ is chosen so that $\angle BP_1P$ is right?

Comment: So as far as I understood, choice of $P$ is arbitrary, am I right?

Comment: Yes. Simson's line is the line containing the points $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$ which are the perpendiculars from a point $P$ on the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$. I hope the language and the picture makes sense. I am studying this for my 10th grade geometry class.

Comment: $P$ has to touch the circle.

Comment: See also [mathworld.wolfram.com/SimsonLine.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimsonLine.html)

Comment: Anyway, I'd say pick a point $P$ on the circle (maybe also between $B$ and $C$, draw a line perpendicular to the line $AB$ and mark intersection as $P_1$. And only then ask to prove that that sum is $180^\circ$. Also, based on elements that are drawn on the picture, I'd say you've been asked to prove that $P_1, P_2$ and $P_3$ lie on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $P$ is arbitrary, and that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are then constructed so that $\angle AP_1P$ and $\angle AP_3P$ are right, we have that

$$\angle AP_1P + \angle P_1PP_3 + \angle PP_3A + \angle P_3AP_1 = 360^\circ$$
$$\angle P_1PP_3 + \angle P_3AP_1 = 180^\circ$$
$$(\angle BPP_1 + \angle BPP_3) + \angle CAB = 180^\circ.$$

Comment: My question is how do you know that $\angle P_1PP_3 + \angle P_3 AP_1 = 180$? The point $P_1$ is outside of the circle.

Comment: I proved it starting from the fact (line 1) that any quadrilateral's interior angles sum to 360 degrees. I then subtracted (line 2) the two angles that are known to be 90 degrees.